# Qt Creator with VLFeat

Tags: c++, qt, vlfeat

So I'm trying to use C++ VLFeat library with Qt. I tried to add the following instruction in the make arguments  :
-I C:/vlfeat-0.9.20 -L C:/vlfeat-0.9.20/bin/win64 -lvl -lm ( I found it somewhere on Google ...)
The following error message appeared:
Symbolic links not supported : disabling -L

I also tried to add paths to libs and dlls in the .pro file of the project to the variable LIBS but the library was still not linked to Qt.

Does anyone know how solve this please ?

Comment: You should rather modify .pro-file, not the make-file. Calling qmake will overwrite all your changes. What is your OS and compiler, win64/mingw?

Comment: Yes, I used win64/mingw.